# I have difficulty in making a fragment trigger an alarm. here is my Activity and the fragment

Tags: java, android

Here is my Activity Class that initiate the Alarm Manager and on pressing the button found on my fragment gives error!

Activity -

```
public class Schedule extends AppCompatActivity
{
    CardView cardView = null;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    Context context;


    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_timeline_icon,
            R.drawable.ic_schedule_icon,
            R.drawable.ic_explore_icon
    };

    public Schedule() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);

        //initilize this variable
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv);


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Profile(), "PROFILE"); // `new Profile()` should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Scope(), "SCOPE");  // `new Scope()` should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new Explore(), "EXPLORE");  // `new Explore()` should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();


        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        this.context = this;
    }

    public void alarmHouse() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }`
```

//here is the Fragment class for the Alarm

```
public class Scope extends Fragment {

    protected static Button txtDate, txtDateEnds, txtTimeIn, txtTimeOut; // static View references are an anti-pattern
    Context context;


    public Scope() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scope, container, false);

    txtDate = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_termBegins);
    txtDateEnds = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_termEnds);
    txtTimeIn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.time_in);
    txtTimeOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.time_out);
    assert txtDate != null;
    assert txtDateEnds != null;
    assert txtTimeIn != null;
    assert txtTimeOut != null;
    termBegins();
    termEnds();
    periodTimeIn();
    periodTimeOut();


    return view;

}

public void termBegins() {
    txtDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SectionEndsDate mDatePicker = new SectionEndsDate();
            mDatePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select date");
        }
    });
}

public void termEnds() {
    txtDateEnds.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SectionBeginsDate mDatePicker = new SectionBeginsDate();
            mDatePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select date");
        }
    });
}

public static class SectionEndsDate extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year_x, month_x, day_x);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year_x, int month_x, int day_x) {
        txtDate.setText("Section Begins: " + String.valueOf(day_x) + " - " + String.valueOf(month_x + 1) + " - " + String.valueOf(year_x));
    }
}

public static class SectionBeginsDate extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year_x, month_x, day_x);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year_x, int month_x, int day_x) {
        txtDateEnds.setText("Section Ends: " + String.valueOf(day_x) + " / " + String.valueOf(month_x + 1) + " / " + String.valueOf(year_x));
    }
}

public void periodTimeIn() {
    txtTimeIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
            schedule.alarmHouse();
            TimeInPicker mTimePicker = new TimeInPicker();
            mTimePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select time");

        }
    });
}

public void periodTimeOut() {
    txtTimeOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TimeOutPicker mTimePicker = new TimeOutPicker();
            mTimePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select time");
        }
    });
}


public static class TimeInPicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        txtTimeIn.setText("Time In: " +
                String.valueOf((hourOfDay == 0 || hourOfDay == 12) ? 12 : hourOfDay % 12) + " : "
                + String.valueOf((minute < 10) ? "0" + minute : minute) + " " + (hourOfDay < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));


    }
}


public static class TimeOutPicker extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        txtTimeOut.setText("Time Out: " +
                String.valueOf((hourOfDay == 0 || hourOfDay == 12) ? 12 : hourOfDay % 12) + " : "
                + String.valueOf((minute < 10) ? "0" + minute : minute) + " " + (hourOfDay < 12 ? "AM" : "PM"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of your Activity class  and trying to call its method like a normal Java class.

```
Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
schedule.alarmHouse();
```

In this case, you'll not have the application context which is needed to set the alarm in `alarmHouse()`.

You need to use `getActivity()` to call any public method of the container activity from your fragment.
So it would be like -

```
`getActivity().alarmHouse();`
```